# mysql convert encoding and insert from database to database

Tags: php

this script is supposed to show all the ligne in the windows-1256 encoding in the mother database thene connecte to target base and convert the ligne from the mother data base and inserted into the target database but it just insert the first ligne and say:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\update-from-txt\conv.php on line 17

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
<h1>table_mother</h1>
id ||||||||||| 3onwan<br>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","labase_mother");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM source");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['ident'] . " |" . $row['titre'];
$titre_convi= $row['titre'];
$identifient= $row['ident'];

//test convert
//convertire
$convert = iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', $titre_convi );
//connection
$con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","labase_target");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//insertion
$result = mysqli_query($con2,"insert into target(ident1, titre1) values ('$identifient',  '$convert')")or die(mysqli_error($con2));

//fin test convert

echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
mysqli_close($con2);
?>
<h2>table_target</h2>
id ||||||||||| 3onwan<br>
<!--resultat-->
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","labase_target");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM target");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['ident1'] . " |" . $row['titre1'];
echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your query fails somewhere thats the error.

Comment: As I see line 17 is your first query than you should check the query on line 15, use backtick in table and column names, sometimes without them the query can fail.

Answer (score 0):

this solve the problem

```
$convert= str_replace("'", "", $convert);

$result1 = mysqli_query($con2,"insert into target(ident1, titre1) values ('".$identifient."', '$convert')")or die(mysqli_error($con2));
```